# Next Js (13.4.4-canary.2) NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL in undefined

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, next.js13

I have a simple .env file

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

I also have a .env.local file

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

I am using the new nextjs app folder structure inside src folder

and my next version is

> "next": "^13.4.4-canary.2",

I am trying to get my NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL variable on client side and doing simply

```
console.log(NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL);
```

And it is always undefined

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

`console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL)`

Comment: I did that but it is not working at all.

Comment: Just restart the server